# WatchKit and sharing content

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to share content (Email, SMS, ...) witch WatchKit ?

All I can found on google is about sharing data between the Watch & the iPhone (eg. CoreData or NSUserDefaults).

The framework allows us to add a menu item with the "Share" icon, so what is the idea behind that ?

```
[self addMenuItemWithItemIcon:WKMenuItemIconShare
                        title:@"Share"
                       action:@selector(share:)];
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an icon. The social framework doesn't exist in WatchKit.